# How to call default interface method from another subclass?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, default-method

Consider the following:

```
//Fooable.java
public interface Fooable {
    public default void foo() {
        System.out.println("Fooable::foo");
    }
    //Lots of other non-default methods...
}

//MyFooable.java
public class MyFooable implements Fooable {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("MyFooable::foo");
    }
    //implements other methods in Fooable...
}

//MyAdvancedFooable.java
public class MyAdvancedFooable extends MyFooable {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        Fooable.super.foo();
        System.out.println("MyAdvancedFooable::foo");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyAdvancedFooable().foo();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to call `foo()` in `Fooable` from `MyAdvancedFooable` (a subclass of `MyFooable`). However, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

MyAdvancedFooable.java:4: error: not an enclosing class: Fooable
        Fooable.super.foo();

if I try `MyAdvancedFooable extends MyFooable implements Fooable` I get the following:

MyAdvancedFooable.java:4: error: bad type qualifier Fooable in default super call
        Fooable.super.foo();
  method foo() is overridden in MyFooable

How can I resolve this problem without having to create a new anonymous implementation of Fooable?

Comment: This is an interesting question, does anyone know what's the pros of using this type of design?

Answer (score 3):

You can only call a method one level up so you would need

```
Fooable.super.foo();
```

in `MyFooable`, while just calling `super.foo()` in `MyAdvancedFooable`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `MyAdvancedFooable extends MyFooable implements Fooable`. Then create another interface, `AnotherFooable`, for example, instead of `Fooable`, as follows:

```
public interface AnotherFooable implements Fooable {
    public default void foo() {
        Fooable.super.foo();
    }
}

public class MyAdvancedFooable extends MyFooable implements AnotherFooable {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        AnotherFooable.super.foo();
        System.out.println("MyAdvancedFooable::foo");
    }
}
```

See:
[Create another interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525975/default-methods-and-interfaces-extending-other-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just `super.foo()` or `this.super.foo()` as it is the parent of the object and not of the class as implied by `Fooable.super.foo()`.

Comment: The OP wants to call the `foo()` method from the interface. Your solution would call the method in `MyFooable` instead